# How do get response data in a firefox extension with webRequest.onBeforeRequest on a site that blocks connections

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Im trying to middle man all requests made to a website using `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` and then using `webRequest.filterResponseData` to get the body, the issue is that with the way this site works with events is that the client sends a post request, and the server will block that connection until an event goes through. This in combination with my firefox extension will cause all requests to block. Im not sure how should go about fetching the response bodies.

```js
function listener(details) {
  let filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
  let decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");

  filter.ondata = (event) => {
    let data = decoder.decode(event.data, {stream: true})
    console.log(data)
    filter.disconnect();
  }

  return {};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  {urls: ["*://*.omegle.com/events"]},
  ["blocking"]
)
```